# Can you specify 'unlimited' when using "Select TOP (@variable) * From"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2005 or later you can use following syntax to return a a variable number of rows:

```
Declare @Limit Int
Set @Limit=5
Select Top(@Limit) * From TableName
```

Is there some magic value, that you can use to let it return all rows? (Thinking of parametrized stored procedure here).  Setting limit as `0` will just return no rows, and using negative value will generate run-time error.

I am pretty sure this is not possible, but I haven't found a definite answer. Having this work without `If/Else` block and duplicating the rather complicated query would be nice.

Comment: Can you perform a query in the `Set` clause? If so then you could just do `Set @Limit = select count(*) from Tablename`.

Comment: you can surely do that using dynamic TSQL

Comment: Could you use `PERCENT` to achieve your goal?  `SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT...`

Comment: There's not a particularly good reason for writing `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *`... why not just `SELECT *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid rewriting the query, which I'm assuming is more complicated than the SQL in the question, you could return the row count to replace the variable in a certain case, for example, if the variable = 0, then return all:

```
declare @Limit Int
set @Limit = 0

if @Limit = 0
    // get the row count from the table you are querying if @Limit = 0
    select @Limit = count(1) from TABLE_NAME

// then use the value in your query as before
select top(@Limit) * from TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Nice, even though the query is fairly complex and I do not want to repeat it in the count statement - I can use just the count on the main table to retrieve the upper bound

Comment: To copy my comment from an earlier deleted answer: If a row is being added, and it ends up added between the time you determine the count and the time you actually select the data, you'll be missing a row, and not necessarily the one that just got added.

Comment: @SebastianK I was going to add querying the main table to the answer, but I wasn't sure if you were joining on multiple tables.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer would be to convert to `bigint` and use its maximum possible value (9223372036854775807). Since that many rows cannot possibly be part of any table, you can be sure you won't miss anything.

Comment: Why is it impossible that there might be 2^63 rows in a table?

Comment: If he had a table with 2^63 rows I don't think he'd ever want to return them all

Comment: @MaxVernon: According to this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), the max size for a database is 524272 Tb. Since numbers this big make my head hurt, I plugged `[math]::pow(2,63) -gt 524272tb` into a powershell prompt and got `True`. So, unless you can get your rows to be less than one byte, you'll never have a table with that many rows in it.

Comment: @MaxVernon I was thinking even simpler: SQL Server's `COUNT_BIG(*)` returns `bigint` and is designed to never fail (unlike `COUNT(*)`).

Answer (score 2):

A way I would do this is to conditionally use `TOP` when limit is not -1 so that when you want all results it can be done.

```
Declare @Limit Int
Set @Limit=5
IF @Limit = -1
    SELECT * FROM tbl_Products
ELSE
    Select Top(@Limit) * From tbl_Products
```

Comment: Take a look at your IF statement

Comment: Yeah, that is cool, I was looking for some way where I do not have to duplicate the query though - I kept it simple in the question, to not detract from point, but the query I have is rather complex

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a number use TOP 100 Percent in your top clause. Let the percentage handle the numbers.

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *
FROM TABLE_Name
```

If you plan to use this inside a stored procedure simply use IF..ELSE Logic as follows .....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
 @Top_N  INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

 IF (@Top_N IS NULL)
   BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
   END
 ELSE
   BEGIN
      SELECT TOP (@Top_N) * FROM TABLE_NAME
   END

END
```

Using Percent pass default value of 100% as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
 @Top_N  INT = 100
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT TOP (@Top_N) PERCENT * FROM TABLE_NAME

END
```